# How can we query Azure Synapse table from Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-synapse

How can we query azure synapse table from azure logic apps.To fetch all the rows

Comment: Can you please share a screen shot or what have you tried?

Comment: Are we talking SQL here or Spark?

Comment: Is your table in dedicated pool or Serverless?

Comment: It's about SQL and It's the Serverless. Anyway I  got the answer

Comment: Please post it as an answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

I had connected using SQL Server connection

1.Connection name: Enter a name

2.Authentication type:  SQL Server Authentication

3.SQL Server Name: Synapse Workspace,Copy Serverless SQL Endpoint

4.Database name: Name of your database

5.Username: Choose `Properties` (inside Settings tab) from the left menu bar and copy the username inside the `SQL admin username` field

6.Password: Choose `(reset admin password)` and enter new password and save the passsword.

7.Gateway: Not needed (Only required in case of fetching from external system)